# image manipulation with assets 2

Tags: assets

is it true that assets 2 does not support image manipulations anymore? 
I just had a hard time debugging a site after updating to assets 2. 
I'm on EE 2.5.5 and assets 2.0.2

it was one of my favorite things in assets 1.x... and I cannot find it in the docs anymore!

at least the following is not working anymore:

```
{my_matrix_field}
    {matrix_cell_assets_fieldtype:url:image_manipulation}
{/my_matrix_field}
```

this still works:

```
{my_matrix_field}
    {matrix_cell_assets_fieldtype:url}
{/my_matrix_field}
```

I am on matrix 2.4.2 and I cannot update to the latest version because of some other bug.

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 4):

After debugging the matrix update from 2.4.2 to 2.5.2 it all began to work again. 
so image manipulations are still supported with assets 2.0.2, it's just not in the docs yet.

btw: this thread helped a lot: 
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/matrix_2_5_upgrade_error

Comment: This was a bug for Matrix rendering fields with parameters within Matrix.

Glad you figured out how to work past the Matrix upgrade bug and get it all working again!

Also, I'll make sure that the image manipulations are mentioned in the docs - just a small oversight there..